# change the background color and then return to original color when timer runs out

Tags: button, background-color

I need some help. Is there any way wherein the background color of the button will return to original form when timer runs out without typing a lot of CSS code again? Is it possible to import the entire CSS style in the Javascript? You will notice that when the timer runs out, the background is still red, I want it to be back to original gradient colors.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.buttonStyle
{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #b9f005), color-stop(1, 

#98bf45));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #b9f005 5%, #98bf45 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b9f005 5%, #98bf45 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #b9f005 5%, #98bf45 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #b9f005 5%, #98bf45 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #b9f005 5%, #98bf45 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b9f005', 

endColorstr='#98bf45',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#b9f005;
    border:1px solid #92e307;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:7px 34px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #86ae47;
    width:150px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
}
.buttonStyle:hover {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 6px #cbfc60;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 6px #cbfc60;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 6px #cbfc60;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #98bf45), color-stop(1, 

#b9f005));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #98bf45 5%, #b9f005 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #98bf45 5%, #b9f005 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #98bf45 5%, #b9f005 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #98bf45 5%, #b9f005 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #98bf45 5%, #b9f005 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#98bf45', 

endColorstr='#b9f005',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#98bf45;
}
.buttonStyle:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

</style>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    var t;
    var isTimeron = false;
    var counter = 0;
function changeBG()
{
document.getElementById("but1").style.background="red";
}

    function stopMe()
    {
        isTimeron = false;
            clearTimeout(t);

    }

    function countdown()
    {
    document.getElementById("but1").value = counter;
        counter--;
        if (counter <= -1)
        {
stopMe();
document.getElementById("but1").value = "ROBOT COIN GAME";
enableVisit();
return;
    }
        t = setTimeout("countdown();", 1000);
    }

    function startMe()
    {
        if (!isTimeron)
        {
            counter = 5; //in seconds
            isTimeron = true;
            countdown();            
        }

    }


     </script>
</head>

<body>


<a href='' target = '_blank'><input title="punyeta" type = "button" id = "but1" value = "ROBOT COIN GAME" 

class='buttonStyle' onclick = "startMe(); changeBG();"/></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using in your javascript

```
document.getElementById("buttonID").style.background= '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #b9f005), color-stop(1, #98bf45))';
```

Change 'buttonID' to the id of your button.

Comment: the button should become green in color again with gradients, not black.

Comment: Change #000000 to the code to make it green with gradients. Like in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Add another class with a red background and use the `!important` flag.

`.buttonStyleRed { background: red !important }`

Then add the new class to the element in your `setTimeout` and remove it when the timer has expired. The `!important` should override the normal background when you add it to the element. When you remove it from the class list for that element, the regular css background from `.buttonStyle` should be back in effect.

`document.getElementById("but1").classList.add("buttonStyleRed");`

`document.getElementById("but1").classList.remove("buttonStyleRed");`